# How to protect a file with Win32 API from being corrupted if the power is reset?

Tags: winapi

In a C++ Win32 app I write a large file by appending blocks about 64K using a code like this:

```
    auto h = ::CreateFile(
        "uncommited.dat",
        FILE_APPEND_DATA,       // open for writing
        FILE_SHARE_READ,        // share for reading
        NULL,                   // default security
        CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);                  // no attr. template

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) { ::WriteFile(h, 64K);}
```

As far as I see if the process is terminated unexpectedly, some blocks with numbers i >= N are lost, but blocks with numbers i < N are valid, and I can read them when the app restarts, because the blocks themselves are not corrupted.

But what happens if the power is reset? Is it true that entire file can be corrupted, or even have zero length?

Is it a good idea to do

```
FlushFileBuffers(h);
MoveFile("uncommited.dat", "commited.dat");
```

assuming that MoveFile is some kind of an atomic operation, and when the app restarts open "commited.dat" as valid and delete "uncommited.dat" as corrupted. Or is there a better way?

Comment: The solution is to invest into a [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply). You cannot guard software against the hardware malfunctioning. Your proposed alternative suffers from the very same problem, when power is lost while the `MoveFile` call is in flight.

Comment: Is not MoveFile an atomic operation? Does not NTFS guarantee that if there is "commited.dat" then it is valid? I mean that the file can be either "commited.dat" or "uncommited.dat", but not "unXQERQR.XXx"

Comment: It may be atomic at the specification layer, but deep down, where data hits the platter, there's just not anything you can do to shield against power outage. What's a magnet to do, when it loses current after having written 7 out of 8 bits?

Comment: You could write a string at the end of the file to indicate successful copy completion, combined with auto-save every few minutes...

Comment: IInspectable, Did you mean that there is no protection on fully serviceable hardware, even if, for example, a specific high-quality SSD disk is used on a server? How database transactions work in this case?

Comment: NTFS is a journaling file system, that file is not going to get corrupted.  Whether all of that data actually makes it to the disk is however not ensured.  Do worry a bit about what will happen when WriteFile() returns FALSE, not unusual, and you'll be half-way to finding the proper approach.

Comment: Barmak Shemirani, Hans Passant, should I use FlushFileBuffers and MoveFile?

Comment: I got confused, I thought you are using `CopyFile`, so my recommendation doesn't apply. SSD may write the file in to temporary cache, some SSDs have a small capacitor which holds enough charge to write the cache in to permanent storage, even if there is power outage. So if the SSD reports the operation was successful, you can take its word. I am not sure if that relates to `FlushFileBuffers` By the way, use the @ symbol for ping, example @HansPassant

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani, Anyway, I should do an operation to commit the changes made to the file. Obviously there should be FlushFileBuffers. And probably moving the file does not completely protect my app from power loss, but it make the app safer at least. Moving is a short operation that changes the attribute of entire file.

Comment: @Hans Passant, should I use FlushFileBuffers and MoveFile? Or some other operation to commit the changes made to the file?

Comment: @IInspectable, Did you mean that there is no protection on fully serviceable hardware, even if, for example, a specific high-quality SSD disk is used on a server? How database transactions work in this case? After googling the subj. I have an impression that they also are not completely safe.

Comment: Presumably, data centers have power failover infrastructure in place, the kind you'll find in hospitals or other mission critical systems. They solve the problem by not allowing it to happen.

Comment: You have a simple file operation. Just call `CloseHandle(h);` and move the file. Check the return handle from `MoveFile`. `MoveFile` is synchronous, it returns true if the operation was successfully completed. If there was power outage you wouldn't get a confirmation anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable How mission critical organizations update drivers or the system? What if installing a new driver, for example, results in the blue screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For append only scenario you can split data in blocks (constant or variable size). Each block should be accompanied with some form of checksum (SHA, MD5, CRC).

After crash you can read sequentially each block and verify it's checksum. First damaged block and all following it should be treated as lost (eventually you can inspect them and recover manually).

To append more data, truncate file to the end of last correct block.

You can write two copies in parallel and after crash select one with more good blocks.

Comment: I am considering this option. Probably it is the best one. But I need two checksums for a block - the first for block size (that is 8 bytes integer) and the second for the block itself, because the blocks are of variable sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`MoveFile` can work all right in the right situation. It has a few problems though--for example, you can't have an existing file by the new name.

If that might occur (you're basically updating an existing file you want to assure won't get corrupted by making a copy, modifying the copy, then replacing the old with the new), rather than `MoveFile` you probably want to use [`ReplaceFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-replacefilea).

With `ReplaceFile`, you write your data to the uncommitted.dat (or whatever name you prefer). Then yes, you probably want to do `FlushFileBuffers`, and finally `ReplaceFile` to replace the old file with the new one. This makes use of the NTFS journaling (which applies to file system metadata, not the contents of your files), assuring that only one of two possibilities can happen: either you have the old file (entirely intact) or else the new one (also entirely intact). If power dies in the middle of making a change, NTFS will use its journal to roll back the transaction.

NTFS does also support transactions, but Microsoft generally recommends against applications trying to use this directly. It apparently hasn't been used much since they added it (in Windows Vista), and MSDN hints that it's likely to be removed in some future version of Windows.

Comment: If I write the data to "uncommited.dat" and then do FlushFileBuffers and MoveFile("uncommited.dat", "commited.dat"). Is it true that if "commited.dat" exists when the app restarts after the power loss, it is not corrupted? Or at least does NTFS specification guarantee that? And does NTFS use journaling in this case?

Comment: It is a problem if I loose the file. I only need to make the app recover correctly after the power loss.

Comment: This file is some kind of a data cache, something like a persistent queue. If I do not have neither "uncommiter.dat" nor "commited.dat" after restart, my app continues to process the new data that it receives and loses its cached data.